# NGINX proxy behind AWS ELB

Tags: nginx, proxy

I've seen documentation showing how to force https when NGINX is sitting behind an ELB load balancer.

What I have is an NGINX proxy server that proxies request to different endpoints. This works NGINX is running on an EC2 instance exposed to the internet.

Internet Request --> NGINX Proxy --> Endpoint or Application

What I'm not clear on or whether it's too complicated is introducing an ELB

Internet Request --> ELB -- NGINX Proxy --> Endpoint or Application

I think trying to route that would be a nightmare :(

Comment: What you want? Force users to HTTPS from HTTP?

Comment: As per the question I just read before this one, in your scenario you can replace Nginx with the ELB at AWS: https://serverfault.com/questions/866365/is-it-possible-to-deploy-front-end-and-back-end-on-two-different-servers-with-sa